# How to have a Reporting Services parameter value automatically selected when another is Selected

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting

I'm working on SSRS with data from SSAS to create reports .

In a multi-value parameter I want to auto select a parameter's values when another is selected .

For example:In Month parameter ; selecting the 6th month in the values list will select all the values from the 1st to the 6th. Or checking a Parameter's value will check the previous value too.

The procedure will be similar to checking the "Select All" option wich checks all the available values.

Any suggestion would be most welcome.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify: when selecting a specific value for a given parameter, do you want to auto-select other values for the **same** parameter, or for a different parameter?

Comment: @MarkBannister . For the same parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bind the second parameter to the first in one of two ways.  For both I would set up 'datasets' to be used to bind to the parameters.

1. You can set a 'Filter' on a dataset to return only a criteria.
2. You can have a predicate in a second dateset that references a parameter set by the first parameter.

EG: So if I had a 'person' data set: (both of these should work in SSRS 2008 or 2012)

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

Select top 100 *
from @Person p
```

And then an 'orders' data set:

```
declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Shoes', 52),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),(4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30),
(6, 'Shirt', 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80)

select *
from @Orders
```

If I set up a Person variable that used 'get data from query' and I set up the 'PersonID' to be the value and 'person' to be the label.  I can then set up a second parameter that gets it's value from the first by adding either a filter or a where clause like:

```
select *
from @Orders 
where PersonID in (@Person)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts . The data is being extracted from SSAS . So my objective here is to auto-check the checkboxes in the multi-value parameter.

Comment: This should do that.  It will merely limit scope from 20 items to the 4 or 5 it would apply to.  If you want it to auto populate and then 'run' so to speak you may choose: 'Default Values' for the second parameter.  You can even make it 'hidden' if you don't want the user to see it.  Or else populate it without a predicate for the 'available values' and then with the predicate for the 'default values'.  This method would allow a user to get a default run, but they could override it after that if they wanted to change selections.

Comment: You cannot populate the same parameter for itself.  The best you could do would be to populate a dataset that relates to the parameter seperately.  You cannot do recursive operations to my knowledge with SSRS.  The parameter is a forward looking operation.  It wants input to do something on something else, it cannot get input and update itself, only something further down the chain.  However you could use a similar dataset many times and just use different predicates on it and lable it different.  I could use orders n times and get n different results if I keep operations going on it.

Comment: Populating a dataset related to the parameter is completely logical and I think it's a good idea .
The way I want to do it is like when checking the "Select all" Checkbox : it selects all the other values .. if i could know how the select all checkbox operates I might be able to achieve what I want ..

Comment: You need to populate a second dataset with what you want from a query:  Select (items) form set where (items) in (@Param1).  Then make this your 'default values' in a second parameter that recognizes this query, @Parameter2.  Then use Parameter2 for your main predicate where statement.